# JWT or HTTP Authorization header not working on live server

Tags: php, http, jwt

Good Morning,

I am generating a JWT access token and using an HTTP Authorization header to grant access to the users, somehow when I try to run it on my local server in postman, and after setting the token in the authorization under Bearer Token it is running on my local server but the live server does not seem to receive the access token.

```
<?php
    include_once 'config/database.php';
    require "../vendor/autoload.php";
    use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    $secret_key = "prosper_api";
    $jwt = null;
    $databaseService = new DatabaseService();
    $conn = $databaseService->getConnection();

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $authHeader = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];

    $arr = explode(" ", $authHeader);

    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "sd" .$arr[1]
    ));

    $jwt = $arr[1];

    if($jwt){
        try{
            $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $secret_key, array('HS256'));
            print_r($data);
            $q = $conn->query("INSERT INTO form (data) VALUES('$data')");
            if($q){
                http_response_code(200); //200 is ok
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "status"  => 1,
                    "message" => "Form data has been added" 
                ));
            }else{
                http_response_code(500); //500 is internal server error
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "status" => 0,
                    "message" => "Failed to create data" 
                ));
            }

            //Access is granted. Add code of the operation here 
            //echo json_encode(array(
            //    "message" => "Access granted:",
            //    "error" => $e->getMessage()
            //));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        http_response_code(401);
        echo json_encode(array(
            "message" => "Access denied.",
            "error" => $e->getMessage()
        ));
    }
}else{
    http_response_code(500); //500 is internal server error
    echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => 0,
        "message" => "Something went wrong with JWT" 
    ));
}
?>
```

Comment: could I need to add an htaccess file so that PHP does not ignore the authorisation header?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the issue, apparently PHP authorization headers are deactivated by default, 
had to add the following lines to my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```